# Как наложить тень блока (box-shadow) на его границу (border)?

Tags: css

Т.е. чтобы тень начиналась на самой границе (border), а не после неё. Про использование 2-ой тени знаю, но вопрос именно про border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно границу дать блоку, а тень - его псевдоэлементу. Такой вариант решает задачу?

```css
.border-and-shadow {
  border: 12px solid yellow;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
.border-and-shadow:after {
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 24px 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-and-shadow"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно уменьшить размер блока, по границе которого генерируется тень, на количество пикселей границы.

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px -5px rgba(255,0,0,0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class=block></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но это всё таки не то. Наверно только двойную тень с растяжением нужно использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что вот так можно

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:6px solid red;
}
div:before {
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  content: '';
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%; 
  pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow:3px 3px 0px #000;
}
```

```html
<div>Текст</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:5px solid red;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 25px #000;
}
div > div {
  border: none;
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height: 200px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 25px #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Text
  <div></div>
</div>
```